# "Analysis of..." or "An analysis of..." - how should I start a title of an academic paper?

Tags: articles

I'm writing an academic essay and I'm wondering whether I should start like "An analysis of sorting algorithms" or "Analysis of sorting algorithms", the question is about the article "an" versus no article. What's the correct way? Or does it depend on a context?

Comment: However you like. Preferably with a pun if possible. Questions like this are better suited for the [academia.se] site though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest "An Analysis of Sorting Algorithms" if the purpose is to introduce your particular analysis on the topic.

Likely, you've introduced the parameters of your research in the paper itself, so the "analysis" in the title of your paper refers to your scope of analysis of algorithm sorting. It does not represent the totality of analysis on the topic nor does it represent an undefined amount of analysis on the topic. As such, it is "an analysis", and the article "an" informs the reader that the analysis has a clear scope, that the analysis is *countable*. Without the article, "analysis" loses its sense of scope; it becomes *uncountable* or, in this case, unquantifiable.

Compare:

> Pizza eaten for dinner

with

> A pizza eaten for dinner